# Flutter App with Firestore using Graphql benefits

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, graphql

I have an app built with flutter and firestore as the DB. It works fine the way I need, it's pretty fast (does not have much data), but since a few days ago I started wondering if adding GraphQL in this App would bring any benefits to it?

To give some basic idea, let's say the app is a `Uber eats` like app, with several restaurants and multiple users making requests. I achieved this by with plain Flutter + Firestore. I'm afraid that at some point let's say, the app has lots of users and start to get slow, would GQL help on this aspect?

I found some Flutter packages like [Firegraph](https://pub.dev/packages/firegraph) that looks promising and easy to use.

Hope someone can share some knowledge on this area.

Comment: Opinion based questions are off topic for StackOverFlow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetching the data from firebase has a completely different approach compared to graphql or REST. Its developed in such a way that there's 0 delay. If you are using firestore then using graphQl will make no much difference in terms of performance. Also by checking the source of this package i see that it's fetching a document, saving it in cache and iterating though each document fields. So it's basically adding another layer to fetch data which i think isn't a good idea